# Comparing strings with if in C# code error

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in c# and I'm making a console guess the number game. You enter a number and it tells you to guess higher or lower or if you guessed the number. Anyways, I'm having trouble comparing the answer with the users guess.

I've tried comparing string guess with string answer using a <= in an if statement. I got an error that says "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of 'string' and'string'.
The code:

```
string answer = "537";
string guess = Console.ReadLine();
*if (guess <= answer)*
```

The code with asterisks is the code I'm getting an error from. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and a solution?

Comment: Is `dog` less than or equal (`<=`) `cat` ? it doesn't make any sense. if you need a numeric comparison, convert the strings to a numeric type first

Comment: you have to parse them into a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strings cannot be treated as number, it will only compare if they are equal. if numbers are the input. convert it to int first, both the guess and answer. if the guess will always be a number this would suffice.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(guess) <= Convert.ToInt32(answer))
{
}
```

if not try to do a try catch or Int32.TryParse

Comment: Thank you. I just figured, if the strings were numerical it would work.

Comment: @ThereIsn't1 No worries, if my answer helps, please mark it as answer :)

Comment: Even better to define the `answer` as an `int` instead of a `string` so you only need to parse the `guess`.  Also it's best to use `int.TryParse` so you can check for bad input and ask the user to enter a number instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said that you're a beginner,

`<=` isn't valid for strings.

Imagine if I did this:

```
string foo = "Hello world";
string bar = "Wassup?"

if(foo <= bar)
{
   /// do something
}
```

What, exactly, would `foo <= bar` mean in that context? We could trying to compare the length of the strings (`bar` is shorter than `foo`), the sum of the ASCII values of the characters in each string, or just about anything. It's possible to implement methods that do those things, but none of them make sense in the general case so the language doesn't try, and it shouldn't.

The difference between a `string` and an `int` is that the former is intended to contain character data, like a name or a sentence. Mathematical comparisons like `<=` apply to numeric data, like integers and floating point values. So, to get the behavior you're looking for, you need to convert your text data into a numeric type.

The nature of data types and how they are stored, comparisons, etc. is a nontrivial discussion. But, suffice it to say that the `string` `"123"` is NOT the same as the number (integer, most likely) `123`.

The easiest fix for your code would be something like:

```
string answer = "537";
string guess = Console.ReadLine();

var intAnswer = Int32.Parse(answer);
var intGuess = Int32.Parse(guess);
if (intGuess <= intAnswer)
{
/// do something...
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the user enters anything in the console that is not a valid digit. (Look up `TryParse` for a better solution, but that's beyond the scope of this answer and I think it'll just confuse the issue in this case.)

I'd spend some time reading about data types, `int` vs `string`, etc. This is a reasonable question about something that is *not* obvious to those just getting started.

Keep at it. We all started somewhere, and this is as good a place as any.